# Going from pseudocode to scheme

Tags: scheme, pseudocode

key <-5381
for each character c in w do
key <-33.key + ctv(c)
end for

This is pseudocode for a key function that is to be implemented in scheme but for the life of me I cant figure out how to translate it into actual code. Any help would be appreciated. And ctv is a function that converts each character into its integer value ie a to 1 and z to 26

Comment: What have you tried so far? post the code, also post a sample input with the expected output

Comment: an example would be key("day") = 33 * (33*  (33 * 5381 + ctv(`d')) + ctv(`a')) +
ctv(`y') = 193381411. im tryin to implement a loop but im new to scheme and i dont understand the syntax that well

Comment: the help is much appreciated and yes this is hw but i appreciate the starting point it should be a lot of help

Comment: `(define key
  (lambda (w)
     (let loop ((chars <string->list w>) ; transform the string into a list of chars
             (acc 5381))   ; this is the initial value of the accumulator
    (if <null? chars>              ; if the list of chars is empty
        acc                ; then return the accumulator
        (loop <???>        ; otherwise advance recursion over list
              <???>))))`                                        does this look correct so far. I'm getting confused on the recursion part do i just loop over the list or do i have to call the key function again

Comment: Be careful with the `<>`, those are not meant to be used, they're just placeholders! . And when you call `loop` you'll have to 1) advance the recursion over the list and 2) update the accumulator . This is the interesting part, I urge you to solve it on your own

Comment: Implementing [cdb](http://cr.yp.to/cdb/cdb.txt) in Scheme? Nice. (Those constants, 5381 and 33, look a little too familiar. ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll only give you the general structure of the solution, because this looks like homework and you should try to solve it by yourself:

```
(define (key str)
  (let loop ((chars <???>) ; transform the string into a list of chars
             (acc 5381))   ; this is the initial value of the accumulator
    (if <???>              ; if the list of chars is empty
        acc                ; then return the accumulator
        (loop <???>        ; otherwise advance recursion over list
              <???>))))    ; update accumulator, use `ctv` and apply the formula
```

Notice that we're using recursion to implement looping, we traverse over the parameter `chars` (the list of characters) and use the parameter `acc` for accumulating the result that will be returned at the end. For instance, here's how the value of the `acc` variable gets updated over successive iterations:

```
acc: 5381              ; initial  value,  acc = 5381
acc: 33 * acc + ctv(d) ; processing 'd',  acc = 177577
acc: 33 * acc + ctv(a) ; processing 'a',  acc = 5860042
acc: 33 * acc + ctv(y) ; processing 'y',  acc = 193381411
```

Finally, don't forget to test it, like this:

```
(key "day")
=> 193381411
```